# Adding display:inline-block to :before or :after will make webfont disappear

Tags: ios, css, safari, mobile-safari, font-face

I am using a web font in an `:after` pseudo class. It shows fine on Desktop Chrome and Android Chrome but on iOS Chrome and Safari (iOS 7.1.2, 9.2.1 and 9.3.1) it disappears unless I comment out both `display:inline-block` and `position:absolute` where it then shows the icon immediately to the right with no width.

```
@font-face {

    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('/channels/myFontFolder/fonts/myFont.eot');
    src: url('/channels/myFontFolder/fonts/myFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/channels/myFontFolder/fonts/myFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/channels/myFontFolder/fonts/myFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/channels/myFontFolder/fonts/myFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/channels/myFontFolder/fonts/myFont.svg#my_Font') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


h2 {

    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid $table-row-border-colour;
    background: none;
    font-size: $body-fontSize;
    position: relative;

}

h2:after {

    content: "\e101";
    font-family: myFont;

    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

}
```

It's working fine on another element with, as far as I can tell, the same styling applied.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, needed to add font-weight: bold